# React Render: object.map() is not a function

Tags: ajax, reactjs, components

I needed help identifying why the map function is not working as expected. I am placing an AJAX request in ComponentDidMount and I am able to see the data in a console log however I am unable to access it. I assume the data is not being passed into setState().

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';


export default class Bitcoin extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
  this.state = {
   prices:[]
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
 $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://index.bitcoin.com/api/v0/lookup?time=2017-01-01T06:00:00Z',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    this.setState({prices: data});
  }.bind(this),
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
  }.bind(this)
 });
}

render(){
 const { prices } = this.state;
 return(
  <div>
    <p>
      {
       prices.map(function(price){
             return <p key={price.code}>{price.description}{price.rate}</p>
         })
       }
      </p>
    </div>
    )
   }
 }
```

console output
[image: console]

Comment: An object does not have map function specified. An Array does. Your data response is an object and so it outputs i does not have a map function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your endpoint is returning an object not an array. You can make use of a utility function provided by [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org) that allows you to map over an object.

Also, you should consider using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) to make your AJAX requests as it will help keep your bundle.js file a little lighter weight.

Answer (score 0):

The lookup endpoint doesn't return an array, it returns a JSON object, with "open", "close" and "lookup" attributes. You should just reference these in your render:

```
render(){
 const { prices } = this.state;
 return(
  <div>
    <p>
        <p key={prices.open.price}</p>
        <p key={prices.close.price}</p>
        <p key={prices.lookup.price}</p>
    </p>
  </div>
  )
 }
}
```

I also think that using jquery is a bit heavy with react. It is simpler to use fetch https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch or request https://www.npmjs.com/package/request libraries, especially if you want to think about both client and server side rendering